# Magento move order

Tags: magento-1.9

Can I ask how to move the order being place from Customer Group Not Logged in to customer Group General all the information is the same.

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to assign that customer to group general using mass action function in your customer grid.